How to embed my WebGL build to a wordpress site?
I am trying to embed my webgl build into a wordpress site.
I tried:

uploading my index.html in the media library with wp-admin, then copying the url and embedding directly into the page. The result was a blank page.
uploading the build as a zip file into media library wp-admin, then copying the url and embedding directly into the page. The result was a prompt to download the zip.
using iframe to embed. I hosted it on simmer.io and copied the embed code, before pasting it on wp-admin>pages.

<iframe src="https://i.simmer.io/@Lyra123/lego" style="width:960px;height:600px"></iframe>

Unfortunately, the page does not seem to register it as code. When I previewed the site, it simply displayed my embed code as text.
What shall I try next? Thank you.

why not host it on your own webserver? however i know this has come up before, did you google? cos i know there was a page out there that explained how

If your theme uses a WYSIWYG editor for the pages, then you'll need to be sure to switch to the text mode first before pasting HTML code. Alternatively, you could create a custom PHP template in your theme and paste the code from your HTML into that template.

Thank you very much for your valuable comment. The text mode was the problem:p
